# Refreshing browser on resize after certain amount

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have quite a complex page (responsive) with a lot of scripts running, and rather than trying to recalculate all these scripts when the browser is resized, I simply wish to trigger a refresh when the browser is resized.

Trouble is, that a refresh on browser resize sends Android devices, and some versions of IE into a refresh loop. I was thinking therefore to only refresh the browser after it has been resized a certain amount, and see if that cures the problem, which is what I'm attempting to do below. Though for some reason, the browser won't refresh at all. The counter works fine, but the `window.location.reload();` doesn't appear to be working here (works outside of this function fine). Any ideas as to why this is?

```
var $resizeTolerance = 0;
jQuery(window).on("resize", function(){
$resizeTolerance++;
console.log($resizeTolerance);

if($resizeTolerance > 10) {
  window.location.reload();
}
});
```

Comment: *"I simply wish to trigger a refresh when the browser is resized."* That sounds like a *very* poor user experience.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Why? Do you think users will be resizing their browser a lot while using the website?

Comment: It violates the principle of not doing the unexpected. When I resize my browser, I do not expect a page to completely reload from the server. It's just not a reasonable response to a resize.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ordinarily I would agree, but the page I am working on was written by another agency, and is extremely complex. Given the time restraints on this project, I am currently unable to think of a better way. Time is money!

Comment: Retained visitors/users are money. I would probably run far, far away from a page that did this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **strongly** recommend not doing this, not least because you've said you don't want to *"...[try] to recalculate all these scripts when the browser is resized..."* but of course that's exactly what you're doing: When the page is reloaded, you're repeating all the calcuations. Instead, make sure the calculations are repeatable, then repeat them.

But with that out of the way:

What you're looking for is `setTimeout`, to do something after the user is done resizing the browser:

```
var loadedAt = Date.now();
var resizeHandle = 0;
jQuery(window).on("resize", function(){
  if (Date.now() - loadedAt < 300) {
    // ignore
    return;
  }
  if (resizeHandle) {
    clearTimeout(resizeHandle);
  }
  resizeHandle = setTimeout(reloadPage, 100); // 100ms = 1/10th second
});
function reloadPage() {
  window.location.reload();
}
```

That will wait until a tenth of a second after the last resize event occurs, and then trigger a page refresh. You may want to adjust the time.

It also ignores any resize event within 300ms of when the code hooks up the handler, to ignore the initial resize event the browser apparently sends.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/jinud/2)

---

Side note: This uses `Date.now`, which nearly all browsers have at this point. You can shim it in older browsers like this:

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function() {
        return +new Date();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to have done the trick - thanks! Had this been a personal project of mine, I would have a bit more input in it, but since the client is looking for a 'quick-fix' while we build the new site in a few months, this will have to suffice for the time being!